# How to minimize correlation of variable with data frame in R?

Tags: r, optimization

I have a variable `ZZ` with integer levels 1, 2, or 3 that I would like to make uncorrelated, as much as possible, with the remaining variables in the data frame.

I am essentially trying to re-create the variable by selecting the values 1, 2, or 3 that minimize the correlation of it with the other data frame variables.

How can I accomplish this in R? It's not clear to me how one can implement this mechanism of selecting integers to optimize in R.

I have my function calculates the sum of the absolute values of the correlations.

```
mincorr <- function(x){
  abs(cor(df[, x], df$PS))+ abs(cor(df[, x], df$PROG))+ abs(cor(df[, x], df$RX))

}
```

Here is a sample of part of my data:

```
df <- read.table(text="PS   PROG    RX  ZZ
2   2   1   1
2   3   2   2
2   2   2   1
1   2   1   1
2   2   2   2
2   2   2   3
3   2   1   1
2   2   2   1
2   2   1   2
2   2   1   2", header=T)
```

I think, since the range of possible values (1-3) is small, I can do a grid search.

```
library(NMOF)
gridSearch(mincorr("ZZ"), list(seq(1,3)))$minlevels
```

Of course, the above code fails. Do I need to somehow specify each row of ZZ as a constraint in the list? My data set isn't too big - 700ish rows, but I would imaging this could get unmanageable. Any other methods to do this are greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one very raw but possible solution: we can use simulated annealing to perturb the target vector in such a way that minimizes the correlation coefficient.

```
tmpx <- sort(sample(1:3, size = 100, replace = T))
df <- data.frame(x = tmpx,
                 y = sample(tmpx, prob = (1:length(tmpx))^2),
                 z = sample(tmpx, prob = (length(tmpx):1)^3))

objective_fun <- function(x, df) {
  sum(cor(x, df)^2)
}

objective_sann_simple_swap <- function(x, df) {
  idx <- sample(seq_along(x), size = 2) 
  xx <- x
  xx[idx] <- x[rev(idx)]
  return(xx)
}

optimRes <- optim(par = df$x, 
                  fn = objective_fun, 
                  gr = objective_sann_simple_swap, 
                  method = "SANN", 
                  df = subset(df, select = - x))

newx <- optimRes$par
cor(newx, df)
```

Basically `otim` calls `objective_sann_simple_swap` in each iteration of `SANN` where the magic happens, i.e., we randomlyswap two elements with each other. (If you have another idea, you can put in here). The new vector is evaluated with regard to the objective function `objective_fun`. If it "optimizes" the objective value (correlation towards 0) than with some probability this new vector is kept to produce "offsprings". (Read on how [Simulated Annealing works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing)).

That's basically it. Use more iterations (control parameters in optim, see `?optim`'s section on SANN) for larger vectors. Hope it helps.